# How to set each input parameter of a function to None and verify that an error is returned?

Tags: python, loops, functional-testing, nosetests

I have some function I have to test. In reality I have 9 input params, but I made it 3 to simplify my question

```
def submit(var1, var2, var3)
```

My testcase looks like this:

```
def test_submit_missing(

     var1=default_value1
     var2=default_value2
     var3=default_value3

     print ('\nAssert missing var1 returns error:\n')
     with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as err: 
          self.submit(None, var2, var3)

     print ('\nAssert missing var2 returns error:\n')
     with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as err: 
          self.submit(var1, None, var3)

     print ('\nAssert missing var3 returns error:\n')
     with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as err: 
          self.submit(var1, var2, None)

     #In reality, I have 9 input vars to test
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list of default values, set n-th element to `None` in a loop and use argument unpacking to pass arguments to the function under the test, example:

```
values = [default_value1, default_value2, default_value3]
for i in xrange(len(values)):
    print ('\nAssert missing var%s returns error:\n' % i)
    params = values[:]
    params[i] = None
    with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as err:
        self.submit(*params)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you know how I can print each variable name? The actual vars are not numerically named.

Comment: Well, you can use a dict instead of a list, for example `{'var1': default_value1, 'var2': default_value2 ...}` and use keyword argument unpacking: `**values`..

Answer (score 0):

What about some thing like this:

```
class SomeException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        super(SomeException, self).__init__(key)


def submit(**kargs):
    for key, val in kargs.items():
        if not val:
            raise SomeException(key)


try:
    submit(var1=1, var2=None)
except SomeException as err:
    print 'No value for %s' % err.key

try:
    submit(**{'var1': 1, 'var2': 2, 'var3': None})
except SomeException as err:
    print 'No value for %s' % err.key
```

the result will be:

```
No value for var2
No value for var3
```

What's great with this is even if your number of input change the function will still works.

Just after posted I realized that's I miss understood the question so here is my answer:

```
 name = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']
 val = ['val1', 'val2', 'va3l', 'val4']

 for i in range(len(name)):
     tmp = list(val)
     tmp[i] = None
     with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as err:
         self.submit(**zip(name, tmp))
```

So I have two list:

- one with the name of the input param
- one for the default value

In the for loop I copy the list of default value (we need to keep it for the other iteration)
Then I update an elem of this list and set it to None
Then I use zip to create a dict with this to list and use the keyword argument unpacking to pass the param to the function

Comment: sorry i miss understand the question